# Google Chrome App: Webview behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, behavior, google-chrome-webview

While researching for an issue on `<iframe>` on Chrome Extension, the `<webview>` in Chrome Apps caught my eye and got me interested.

So i decided to do a small example of the issue i am facing on `<iframe>` and see if `<webview>` get it solved. From what i understood of watching a Chrome Dev video,  the `webview` runs in a separate process than your app; it doesn't have the same permissions as your app. So i assume if the content in the  runs in a certain way separated from the 'main thread' (app), i guess their content will be executed separately from each other  not blocking the app or the other  in case any of them could have a possible long running js executon. Therefore i did the following:

### background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  // Tell your app what to launch and how.
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
      width: 1800,
      height: 1000
  });
});
```

### manifest.json

```
{
  // Required
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  // Recommended
  "description": "My first packaged app.",
  "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" },
  // "default_locale": "en",

  // Pick one (or none) OF browser_action, page_action, theme, app 

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
    }
  },

  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",

  "permissions": [ "webview" ]

}
```

### window.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Hello, world!</div>
    <webview id="wv1" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://www.google.com"></webview>
    <webview id="wv2" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://www.nytimes.com"></webview>
    <webview id="wv3" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></webview>
    <webview id="wv4" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://db.tt/FCCA7nuz"></webview>
  </body>
</html>
```

Three of those webviews are normal webpages, the fouth is just an example of a long running js file, you can inspect the code or i can provide it later.
If i would open 4 google chrome browser windows, type the address, press enter, what i would observe is: 3 pages loaded imediately and the other with the long js execution would still be working.

If i do this in a webpage, using  to open these 4 webpages, since it is all in the same process, if 1 page is slow/blocks due to js execution, all others will be blocked.

Now with Chrome App, using  i noticed something interesting and weird about the behavior. I notice the following:

1. If i only load the first 3 webpages, the load is fast and 'at the same time' or so it appears;
2. If i load all the webpages as it is, i see the first 3 pages loading and the last since it has a long js execution takes his time and then it shows (this would be the optimal behavior), since their are different proccesses they shouldn't depend on if a webview is slow, others must wait;
3. Now if i comment the third , refresh and execute the app, i see no webview until the one with the longscript is done. (why this happens?)
4. The point above is random either it happens as i mentioned or it doesn't.
5. And for last, let's add another `<webview id="wv5" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://developer.chrome.com"></webview>`, what will happen for me is: the first three get loaded, the fourth is executing and after finished and displayed then i see the fifth rendered.

My main question/doubt is around the  behavior and since they are actually running in a separate process, why it doesn't have same behavious as a browser window for example, why does that webview blocks the others from working/rendering, is it intended to work as it is? Should i do some workaround to detect if a webview after some time isn't finished to skip the load and let others load so then i could go back to the slow ones?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use the events(loadstart and loadstop) provided with webview to log the start time and end time of loading of each webview, so that you can see the sequence of loading whether they are concurrent or sequential.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Webviews run in a different process than your app, but they run in the same process of each other in the same partition. If you don't specify a partition attribute, they will be in the same, default one. If you check the Chrome Task Manager (shift+esc) you will see:
[image]

(notice the Process ID column)

If you instead set each webview to a different partition using the tag attribute:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Hello, world!</div>
    <webview id="wv1" partition="p1" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://www.google.com"></webview>
    <webview id="wv2" partition="p2" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://www.nytimes.com"></webview>
    <webview id="wv3" partition="p3" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></webview>
    <webview id="wv4" partition="p4" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://db.tt/FCCA7nuz"></webview>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will see that each webview now runs in its own process:

[image]

Comment: Really amazing, it works as intended with partition. I assumed by just using the tag webview it would create a process seperately from other webviews. I am really stunned with the capability of the tag webview. Thank you for clearing up the process behavior.

Comment: Is it possible to use the same partition but allow each webview to have a separate process somehow?