# How to run the same application or several windows in a separate process?

Tags: google-chrome-app

Webviews can run in a different process as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635739/google-chrome-app-webview-behavior/16641592#16641592). How to run the same application in a separate process? Can I run different windows of the application in a different process?

Comment: Why would you need it?

Comment: If one window crash won’t affect the app or other windows. And I need run windows in parallel to increase the app productivity.

Comment: The second one is, I think, a snake-oil argument: one process does not mean one thread.

Comment: Maybe you're right. In my application, each window work as single thread. I think, [Multi-process Architecture](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html) will help me to increase performance and stability.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. So each window WILL be a single thread from JS perspective. And being in separate processes is absolutely transparent to your app, so I don't see how you can gain anything.

Comment: Each window is some worker. In addition, Chrome (not JS) can perform some tasks in parallel. JavaScript Multi-threading topic is also very interesting. What about each app? In the end I can run the same application from different directories. But I don't like this idea.

Comment: There's an `<appview> tag` currently in the dev channel only which allows you to run apps within apps.. not sure if you can run the same app though.. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/appview

Comment: @JosephPortelli, good news. Need to test this api.